# laravel 5.4 Method whereDate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

- Laravel 5.4
- PHP 7.0.0

Error message:

> **ErrorException** 
>   Method whereDate does not exist.

Hi everyone I have problem in blade when I use whereDate.

my code:

```
@foreach($game_fields as $game_field)
    @foreach($game_field->games->whereDate('game_start', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datum))->groupBy('group_id') as $game)
        
            {{ $game[0]->group->name}}
            {{ $game[0]->group->games->count() }}
        
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I am trying to display all game fields and in every game field displays all games that will be played by specific $date but group by group_id to show it by groupname like this:

### game field 1

Group name | No. of matches
- Group 1 | 5
- Group 3 | 6
- Group 6 | 4

### game field 2

Group name | No. of matches
- Group 5 | 4
- Group 7 | 6
- Group 11| 4

I have 3 modules: GameField, Group, Games

In Games db table I have:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('team_1_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->integer('team_2_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->integer('game_field_id')->unsigned();
$table->datetime('game_start');
```

Game field table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
```

Group field table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
```

Games module:

```
public function game_field(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\GameField','game_field_id', 'id');
}

public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group','group_id', 'id');
}
```

GameField module:

```
 public function games(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Games','game_field_id', 'id');
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$game_field->games` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, not an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`, you should use

```
@foreach($game_field->games()->whereDate('game_start', \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datum))->groupBy('group_id')->get() as $game)

        {{ $game->group->name}}
        {{ $game->group->games->count() }}

@endforeach
```